# midpoint theorem connections to midpoint formula

Tags: geometry

Is there an elegant way to prove that the midpoint is $\left(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2},\frac{x_2+y_2}{2}\right)$ using non-right angled similar triangles? I know that it's really easy to just by assuming this is true and proving by showing the distance formula gives two equal sides.
Or is there some other way I can relate the midpoint formula to the midpoint theorem (the line segment connecting the midpoints of two sides of a triangle is parallel to the third side and is congruent to one half of the third side).

[image: example of this if a line were joined through $m_1$ and $m_2$]

Comment: The midpoint of what, and what are $x_i,y_i$ ?

Comment: i think $$x_1,y_1$$ and $$x_2,y_2$$ are coordinates of two points

Comment: How do you want to use triangles to prove the above if you only have *two points*?

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the midpoint of $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ is $$M\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$$

The simplest proof of this uses vectors.

$$\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OA}+\frac 12\overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{OA}+\frac 12\left(\overrightarrow{OB}-\overrightarrow{OA}\right)=\frac 12\left(\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

To add to David Quinn:

Consider a line in your diagram passing through the midpoint of AB running parallel to AC. Where does it intersect BC?